# Can you redirect exactly request for "/.html" to index.html?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I mean like example.com/.html redirecting to example.com/index.html.
Like it's literally request for a file named ".htm" – not "whatever.html".

Answer (score 0):

A 301 redirect is a permanent redirect from one URL to another. 301 redirects send site visitors and search engines to a different URL than the one they originally typed into their browser or selected from a search engine results page.

Just try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /.html /index.html

</IfModule>
```